# How to stop the execution and make a redirect to the login page

Tags: c#, asp.net

How to stop the execution and redirect to the login page.
I tried `FormsAuthentication.Signout` but seens it doesn't stop the execution and let the code continue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Response.redirect to the login page

```
FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
Response.Redirect("URLToLoginPage");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use one of the following statements to terminate/keep the page execution.

Response.Redirect(URL,false) :- User is redirected to a second page and the current page on the server will keep processing.

AND

Response.Redirect(URL,true) :- User is redirected to a second page but the processing of the current page is aborted.

Regards.